# Rails Rspec Model Spec User :email ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Trying to figure out why my rspec test is failing. Most notable is the Failure message that seems contradictory. Stating I have an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error and that is exactly what I'm asserting should happen.

Here is my user.rb

```
...
validates_presence_of :email
...
```

Here is my users_spec.rb

```
...
it "is invalid without email" do 
  Factory(:user, email: nil).should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
...
```

here is the output:

```
Failures:

  1) User a user (in general) is invalid without email
     Failure/Error: Factory(:user, email: nil).should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email is invalid, Email can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Originally I was testing it this way but it kept failing, so I decided to specify on what error I was expecting.

```
it "is invalid without email" do 
  Factory(:user, email: nil).should_not be_valid
end
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason your code isn't working is that you're trying to create an invalid model before actually testing it for validity. What you want to do is to create a valid model, change something and check that it is invalid, like this:

```
it "is invalid without email" do 
  user = Factory(:user)
  user.email = nil
  user.should_not be_valid
end
```

I personally like to define my model in a `before` block, set is as the `subject` and then change attributes in each spec and check for validity, like this:

```
before do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

subject { @user }

it "is invalid without email" do
  subject.email = nil
  should_not be_valid
end
```

For the record, if you wanted to test that the record creation raised an error (which is definitely *not* the advisable way to do this), you could do it by wrapping the `Factory` call in a `lambda`, like this:

```
lambda {
    Factory(:user, :email => nil)
}.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Comment: thanks, that totally makes sense. how do you feel about let!(:user) { Factory(:user)} instead of before do ... end?

Comment: btw, why wouldn't you advise *not* wrapping it in a lambda {} or expect {}?

Comment: What I meant was that I wouldn't advise checking for validity by checking that an error is raised. Using `lambda` to check that an error is raised in other contexts is totally fine.